# Scan not working

Tags: pointers, go, reflection, gocql, cqlr

My scan is not updating its destination variable. I sort of got it working with:

```
ValueName := reflect.New(reflect.ValueOf(value).Elem().Type())
```

But I don't think it is working the way I want.

```
func (self LightweightQuery) Execute(incrementedValue interface{}) {
    existingObj := reflect.New(reflect.ValueOf(incrementedValue).Elem().Type())
    if session, err := connection.GetRandomSession(); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    } else {
        // buildSelect just generates a select query, I have test the query and it comes back with results.
        query := session.Query(self.buildSelect(incrementedValue))
        bindQuery := cqlr.BindQuery(query)
        logger.Error("Existing obj ", existingObj)
        for bindQuery.Scan(&existingObj) {
            logger.Error("Existing obj ", existingObj)
            ....
        }
   }
}
```

Both log messages are the exact same `Existing obj &{ 0  0  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0}` (Spaces are string fields.) Is this because of the heavy use of reflection to generate a new object? In their docs it says I should use `var ValueName type` to define my destination but I cannot seem to do that with reflection. I realize this may be silly, but maybe even just pointing me in the direction for further debugging this would be great. My skills with Go are quite lacking!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is it you want exactly? Do you want to update a variable you pass to `Execute()`?

If so, you have to pass a pointer to `Execute()`. And then you only need to pass `reflect.ValueOf(incrementedValue).Interface()` to `Scan()`. This works because `reflect.ValueOf(incrementedValue)` is a [`reflect.Value`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value) holding an `interface{}` (the type of your parameter) which holds a pointer (the pointer you pass to `Execute()`), and [`Value.Interface()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Interface) will return a value of type `interface{}` holding the pointer, the exact thing you have to pass `Scan()`.

See this example (which uses [`fmt.Sscanf()`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Sscanf), but concept is the same):

```
func main() {
    i := 0
    Execute(&i)
    fmt.Println(i)
}

func Execute(i interface{}) {
    fmt.Sscanf("1", "%d", reflect.ValueOf(i).Interface())
}
```

It will print `1` from `main()`, as the value `1` is set inside `Execute()`.

If you don't want to update the variable passed to `Execute()`, just create a new value with identical type, since you're using `reflect.New()` which returns the `Value` of a pointer, you have to pass `existingObj.Interface()` which returns an `interface{}` holding the pointer, the thing you want to pass to `Scan()`. (What you did is you passed a pointer to a `reflect.Value` to `Scan()` which is not something `Scan()` expects.)

Demonstration with `fmt.Sscanf()`:

```
func main() {
    i := 0
    Execute2(&i)
}

func Execute2(i interface{}) {
    o := reflect.New(reflect.ValueOf(i).Elem().Type())
    fmt.Sscanf("2", "%d", o.Interface())
    fmt.Println(o.Elem().Interface())
}
```

This will print `2`.

Another variant of `Execute2()` is that if you call `Interface()` right on the value returned by `reflect.New()`:

```
func Execute3(i interface{}) {
    o := reflect.New(reflect.ValueOf(i).Elem().Type()).Interface()
    fmt.Sscanf("3", "%d", o)
    fmt.Println(*(o.(*int))) // type assertion to extract pointer for printing purposes
}
```

This `Execute3()` will print `3` as expected.

Try all examples on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/DpuUcN3Af3).

Comment: I am accepting a value of any type `incrementedValue` and I am just trying to create an uninitialized new variable of the same type to give to the `bindQuery.Scan()`. I want a second one because I go through and compare all their fields later on. I haven't tested what you posted but I wanted to give a little more detail on why I am trying to do what I am. Essentially the end goal is get the object from the database, compare with the incrementedValue then update the database with the changes between the two. Fairly simple until you want to make it really dynamic.

Comment: @electrometro Then my `Execute2()` and `Execute3()` might be feasible to you. Also a link to try my codes on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/DpuUcN3Af3) is included at the end of my answer.

Comment: The second example was exactly what I needed. It was a long night and as soon as I seen that this morning it made perfect sense. Thanks!